# How to fix "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" when I click button to show data on other table which select option as reference

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I have two table, they are
1. Class table with column, class_id, name
2. Teacher table with column teacher_id, name, class_id

I want to show teacher name with column name on table teacher in same one page blade this is index.blade.php when I choose select option with filled data based on class_id table class. I already succeed fecth data class_id with select option,

[image]
 but when I clicked Show button and change data on select option I get error message like this :

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   No message

This is my code on report folder

### index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>Report List of Classroom</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form action="{{ route('reportshow') }}" method="post">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        {{ method_field('patch') }}

                        @if ($errors->any())
                            <div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul></div>
                        @endif

                    <select id="class_id" class="form-control" name="class_id" width="150">
                        <option value=""> -- Choose Classroom -- </option>
                        @foreach($classroom as $classroom)
                            <option value="{{ $classroom->class_id }}">{{ $classroom->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Show</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div>
                    {{ isset($class_id) ? $class_id : '' }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

====================================

### on controller ReportController.php

```
public function tampil(Request $request)
    { 
        $results = DB::select('select name from teacher where class_id = ?', $request['class_id']);
        return view('report.index', compact('results'));
    }
```

====================================

### on routes/web.php

```
Route::post('reportshow', 'ReportController@tampil')->name('reportshow');
```

I expect to show teacher name with column name on table teacher in same one page blade this is index.blade.php when I choose select option with filled data based on class_id table class, but I get error :

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is telling you that there is no route defined for the method you are using in your form. The route you defined is only available for `POST` methods: `Route::post('reportshow', 'ReportController@tampil')->name('reportshow');` while your form is using the `PATCH` method (by using `{{ method_field('patch') }}`).

Remove that line `{{ method_field('patch') }}` from your form to post using the `POST` method.

More on routing: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

Comment: Thank you @kerbholz now I can use my code after remove line {{ method_field('patch') }}

Answer (score 0):

`MethodNotAllowedHttpException` means the route defined and the route you are using is not matching or their type mismatched.

In your case the route is:

```
Route::post('reportshow', 'ReportController@tampil')->name('reportshow');
```

and the one you are using is:

```
<form action="{{ route('reportshow') }}" method="post">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  {{ method_field('patch') }}
```

here this line `method_field('patch')` is used to override the method as `patch` but the route is of `post` type, that's why the error.

To resolve this, either change the route to:

```
Route::patch
```

or remove

```
{{ method_field('patch') }}
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Since the browser doesn't understand PATCH, PUT, DELETE method you can do one thing. It only understands GET and POST.
Make the following line as:-

```
<form action="{{ route('reportshow') }}" method="patch">
```

And in the subsequent line put the following line:-

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
```

This will just let you through and you won't be getting the following error. Let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: `method="patch"` isn't valid though, only `get`, `post` and `dialog` are